# Use database with missing file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

**Issue**

*Good news*: Lucky me, its not production, but its a big database (TBs) used for performance testing of scripts and stuff

*Bad news*: While performance testing, i experimented with In-Memory tables, creating FileGroup and file in it. However, by my mistake, the file was created on a SSD drive that wipes after restart.

Now, after that restart, the DB is stuck in Recovery pending.
File doesnôt contain anything usefull, actually only one or two table with useless data.

**The question**:
Is there any safe way i can tell SQL server to get rid of the FileGroup and File altogether? Full dataloss in this Memory Optimized FileGroup is acceptable.

Thank you

Comment: This question is off-topic here and better suited to a different StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there any safe way i can tell SQL server to get rid of the FileGroup and File altogether? Full dataloss in this Memory Optimized FileGroup is acceptable*

I don't think it is possible. [The Memory Optimized Filegroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/the-memory-optimized-filegroup?view=sql-server-2017):

> The following limitations apply to a memory-optimized filegroup:
>
> - **Once you create a memory-optimized filegroup, you can only remove it by dropping the database. In a production environment, it is unlikely that you will need to remove the memory-optimized filegroup.**

So the answer is to restore DB from backup.

Comment: What about not getting rid of the filegroup, just the file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, but you might be able to set the memory-optimized filegroup offline, and then simply use/access the other filegroups.